# In Rolemaster Unified, when in the combat round do persistent spell effects occur?

Tags: spells, combat, initiative, rolemaster, rolemaster-unified

Using the lvl 4 spell from "Wind Law" *Stun Cloud I* as an example (Rolemaster Unified Spell Law pg 159), but this question comes up for other spells.

> 4. Stun Cloud I – Creates a 5'R cloud of charged gas particles.
>
> The cloud takes one round to form, so anyone in the radius when it is cast may make a maneuver to move out of the radius without taking a critical; however, after that anyone within the radius at anytime in the round takes the critical indicated (a maximum of one per round). Following the initial formation round, the cloud delivers a C Electricity critical to all within the area of effect on the first and second rounds, a B critical on the third and fourth rounds, and an A critical on the fifth and sixth rounds, after which it dissipates. It drifts with the wind.

When in the initiative order do people in the cloud take a critical?

When in the next round does it fully form?

Do we roll initiative for the spell, or does it use the caster's initiative?

Does it apply the critical in the Upkeep Phase?

> Upkeep Phase: Ongoing effects, such as bleeding, spell durations, etc. are tracked.

*pg 158 Rolemaster Unified Core Law Section 8.3 Round Sequence*

I think this spell may assume rules that are not there in RMU.  In earlier editions persistent spells effects occurred at the end of the round in the "spell resolution" phase.

Answer (score 2):

> In the Rolemaster Unified game, when does a spell like Stun Cloud I
> start hurting people? Does the spell have its own turn or does it use
> the turn of the person who cast it? When does the spell fully form?

The game's rules don't give a clear answer. However, we can make a good guess. The game has a part of each round called the Upkeep Phase, which is when ongoing effects are taken care of. It makes sense to think that the spell would start hurting people during this part of the round.

The Stun Cloud I spell needs one round to form. So, it would likely be fully formed at the end of the round after it was cast. Then, it would start hurting people in the Upkeep Phases of the next rounds.

As for whose turn the spell uses, the rules don't say. But, it would make sense to use the turn of the person who cast the spell. This is because the spell is like an action of the caster.

Comment: I like your answer, but as I understand it, only the action phase has "turns".  If it occurs in the Upkeep phase then all "turns" are over, right?